# Discord4J - Slash Command only in a specific channel

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord4j

I am currently working on a Discord bot using the Discord4J library in Java, and I would like to create a slash command that is only available in a specific channel and is not suggested in other channels.

Currently, I have successfully implemented the slash command and it shows up in all channels where the bot is active. However, I would like the command to be suggested only in a specific channel and not appear in other channels.

I have implemented the command as any other already with the following code. However, there it is displayed in every channel and not only in a specific one as expected:

`List commandData = new ArrayList<>();

```
    commandData.add(Commands.slash("poll", "Erstelle eine Umfrage")
            .setDefaultPermissions(DefaultMemberPermissions.enabledFor(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR))
            .setGuildOnly(true));`
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Community its all code thats necessary to unterstand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the command from the server settings for certain channels.
Unfortunately, you can't edit this via the API (not a Discord4J issue, it's a Discord restriction).

1. Go to the "integrations" settings

[image: "Integrations settings menu"]

2. Select the bot you want to edit

[image: Select the bot]

3. Select the command you want to disable

[image: Select the command you want to disable]

4. Click on "add channel"

[image: Click on "add channel"]

5. Select the channel(s) you want to disable, then effectively disable the command

[image: Select the channel(s) you want to disable, then effectively disable the command]